# Danish characters with Easy APNs

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send Danish characters (Æ, Ø, Å) in an alarm notification using [Easy APNs](http://www.easyapns.com/) but when doing so, no message is send. If I send it with sound, only the sound is send. Also the message will be set to "null" in the database if it includes any of the Danish characters.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by `json_encode()`. Using `utf8_encode()` on my alert views before `json_encode()` solved the issue.

**UPDATE** (How to fix the issue)

**1.** In `class_APNS.php` around line 411, you have

`$msg = chr(0).pack("n",32).pack('H*',$token).pack("n",strlen($message)).$message;`

Above that, put:

`$message = utf8_encode($message);`

**2.** In `class_APNS.php` (same file) put this:

`$usermessage['aps']['alert'] = utf8_encode($usermessage['aps']['alert']);`

Put it just above the following:

```
$fk_device = $this->db->prepare($list[$i]);

$message = $this->_jsonEncode($usermessage);

$message = $this->db->prepare($message);
$delivery = (!empty($when)) ? "'{$when}'":'NOW()';
```

Comment: could you please explain more how you fixed it. where did you exactly changed it to utf-8 and in which class ! thank you.

Comment: @Juono I have updated my answer to explain how to fix the issue.

Comment: thanx for answering my question but this code(below) does not exist in the `class_APNS.php`or at least i can't find it: `if(!$usermessage['aps']['alert']) { $usermessage['aps']['alert'] = NULL; } else { echo $usermessage['aps']['alert']; }`

Comment: Sorry. I think that is one more of my hotfixes. Try if you can find the new code in my answer. I just updated it.